after using Box-Cox in Python the data goes to infinity
after using Box-Cox Conversion in Python the data goes to infinity
It initializes an empty DataFrame df_boxcox to store transformed data.
For each numeric column:
It plots the histogram of the column before transformation.
It applies the Box-Cox transformation to the column to make its distribution closer to normal. This includes shifting the data to ensure all values are positive, then applying the transformation.
It plots the histogram of the transformed column.
It prints summary statistics of the transformed data
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18_F6lKB1F29H2CJ5pKqpQU7tdISJB0If?usp=sharing

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import boxcox

# Read the dataset

df = pd.read_csv("https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=1-5cJxjrObykexFtZdLi1J69lEuQIyemc&export=download&authuser=0&confirm=t&uuid=0d423d2f-d4a0-4038-a8e0-06a93c1d3325&at=APZUnTXfgD62MD3H83qfWuIxdx5I:1714822459800")

# Drop irrelevant columns

df = df.drop(columns=\["Postcode"\])

# Calculate age of buildings

df\["YearBuilt"\] = 2018 - df\["YearBuilt"\]

# Fill missing values

numeric_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
for col in numeric_cols.columns:
df\[col\] = df\[col\].fillna(df\[col\].mean())
df\["CouncilArea"\] = df\["CouncilArea"\].fillna("None")

# Apply Box-Cox transformation

df_boxcox = pd.DataFrame()
for col in numeric_cols.columns:
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

    # Plot histogram before transformation
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    sns.histplot(df[col], kde=True)
    plt.title(f'Histogram of {col} (Before Transformation)')
    
    # Apply Box-Cox transformation
    min_val = df[col].min()
    if min_val <= 0:
        shifted_col = df[col] - min_val + 1
    else:
        shifted_col = df[col]
    transformed_col, _ = boxcox(shifted_col)
    df_boxcox[col] = transformed_col
    
    # Plot histogram after transformation
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    sns.histplot(transformed_col, kde=True)
    plt.title(f'Histogram of {col} (After Transformation)')
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

# Summary statistics of transformed data

print(df_boxcox.describe())

